Unable to use $ sign in Vs code
During writing JS we use $ sign but I am unable to use $ sign in my vs code . My keyboard condition is good. Its functioning in other apps but its not functioning in the vs code. The number 4 is working but when i press shift+4, its not working
I have tried many times but I have failed every time.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

You probably have a keyboard shortcut. Try to disable them. Take a look here: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts or Ctrl+K Ctrl+S.
A second shot is that it is caused by some extension. Maybe disable all extensions, restart VS Code and check if it is working again. After that, enable the extensions one by one and check if one of them breaks your $-sign.
